# Open a large file in Python without running out of RAM

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I'm trying to open a file with 5 million entries in Python

My code needs to fetch inputs line by line in order (a difference of a few tens of lines with ThreadPoolExecutor is not a problem) and then be fetched by ThreadPoolExecutor to send to get_url function

Maybe the url variable is getting too big, ThreadPoolExecutor should itself retrieve them one by one from the file by keeping a line counter? I already tried to do this but failed (this is the first time I use ThreadPoolExecutor)

```
with open("1_1.txt") as stream:
    urls = [line.strip() for line in stream]

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as pool:
    pool.map(get_url, urls)
```

The full code of my script :

```
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import fileinput
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import traceback
from threading import Thread


from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
import warnings

from random import random
from queue import Queue


requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning, module='bs4')

count_requests = 0
host_error = 0


def get_url(url):
    global queue
    global count_requests
    global host_error

    try:
        

        result_request = requests.get(url, verify=False, timeout=40)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(result_request.text, 'html.parser')

        title = soup.title.get_text().splitlines(False)
        
        title = str(title)
        title = title[0:10000]


        count_requests = count_requests + 1
        
        queue.put(f'{url} - {title} \n')
        
      

      
    except:
        queue.put(f'FAILED : {url} \n')
        host_error = host_error + 1


# dedicated file writing task
def file_writer(filepath, queue):
    global count_requests
    # open the file
    with open(filepath, 'a', encoding="utf-8") as file:
        # run until the event is set
        while True:
            # get a line of text from the queue
            line = queue.get()
            # check if we are done
            if line is None:
                # exit the loop
                break
            # write it to file
            file.write(line)
            # flush the buffer
            file.flush()
            # mark the unit of work complete
            queue.task_done()
    # mark the exit signal as processed, after the file was closed
    queue.task_done()
    
    



# create the shared queue
queue = Queue()
# defile the shared file path
filepath = 'output.txt'
# create and start the file writer thread
writer_thread = Thread(target=file_writer, args=(filepath,queue), daemon=True)
writer_thread.start()



# wait for all tasks in the queue to be processed
queue.join()



with open("1_1.txt") as stream:
    urls = [line.strip() for line in stream]

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as pool:
    pool.map(get_url, urls)
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246325/discussion-between-stuart-and-jdm0).

Comment: This post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72927681/ram-that-increases-continuously-with-concurrent-futures-threadpoolexecutor from 10 hours ago is asking the same question and providing the same or at least very similar code. Incase someone solves this issue, they could also give the other poster a little love too!

Comment: [Is this you?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72927681/12671057) Or how come the questions/codes are so similar?

Comment: It was yesterday and I spent a lot of time on it, since I saw that the problem came from this piece of code: urls = [line.strip() for line in stream] and not ThreadPoolExecutor. I am trying to solve it by doing a row counter to fetch the file line by line but threads complicate things

Comment: I'm not sure how much "in order" things need to be. Thread pool is handing chunks of work to different threads, the stuff being queued isn't in order. I think you should ditch the thread pool and feed the threads from a queue like you do with the writer. But the "in order" is a complicatoin.

Comment: I don't need it to be in line-by-line order, but within a few tens or hundreds of lines, the most annoying thing is not to miss lines with a counter, it would be good for example that ThreadPoolExecutor knows how many iterations it is and that I can retrieve the URL in the file according to the line

Comment: `pool.map` is intended to be consumed. You might try adding `from collections import deque`, then changing `pool.map(get_url, urls)` to `deque(pool.map(get_url, urls), maxlen=0)` (a `deque` with a `maxlen` of zero is the lowest overhead way to quickly consume and discard all results from an iterator). Without it, the futures and the results they wrap pile up indefinitely. The eager dispatch is [a known bug in Python](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/74028).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Good point, though note that they said the problem already occurs at the list comprehension (see the chat) and apparently already moved on to the third version of their question.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Ah. Well, that's just "you can't slurp a whole file into memory and not suffer for it". Changing the code to put the processing inside the `with` for the file would allow it to change from listcomp to genexpr, and it would dramatically reduce the memory usage (not trying to slurp the whole file). That said, the problem with `Executor.map` means it would still be fully realized. Since they only use one worker, they could do it with just `map`, not `Executor.map`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, we've been through all that in the chat. Except I still think their numbers don't add up and it shouldn't be as problematic as they're reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with `submit()` method:

```
with open("1_1.txt") as stream:
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as pool:
        for url in stream:
            pool.submit(get_url,url.strip())
```

Comment: `Executor.map` is implemented roughly as a loop that calls `submit` over and over, then waits for and yields the result of each future `submit` returns; if `pool.map(get_url, stream)` has a problem, so will this.

Comment: I know map() method use submit() method internally. But problem is RAM usage because of  "urls = [line.strip() for line in stream] " this line, isn't ?

Comment: That seems to be the case, but your loop is still going to package tasks that store that stripped line in each of them, so it will inherently involve storing all the data that the listcomp stores (on top of all the task wrapping overhead). Avoiding the initial listcomp saves the overhead of that `list` itself (roughly eight bytes per line in the file on a 64 bit system), but saves nothing on the strings (which are at least 6x more expensive, memory-wise).